# VBA - How to invoke Save button on a opened PDF in IE11 (No Sendkeys)

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, internet-explorer

I am new to programming and this is my first question. Thanks in advance for your support.

I have to download PDFs from a website constantly. When clicking on a button it opens a second tab and the PDF shows. The URL appearing on browser address bar is not exactly the URL of the PDF, it is just a generic website that is triggered through tokens to open the PDF.

Since I do not have the URL, I haven't been able to use URLDownloadToFile option. This option as well corrupts the PDFs and it hasn't been working for me. I was unable to use XMLHTTP since it requires a URL as well.

Unless you have other suggestions, I think clicking the Save button appearing on the frame of the PDF opened in IE could be the solution. I wound't like to use send keys since it is going to be a process running while the PC is locked. I already know how to manipulate the "Save As" window. I do not know how to invoke the Save button. Can some one show me how to do this?

![IE PDF Screen][This is the button I want to invoke][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTPs7.jpg)

Comment: *since it is going to be a process running while the PC is locked* - VBA and Office automation is absolutely not designed to run unattended. Consider writing (and scheduling) a PowerShell script instead. That said, this is more of a whiteboard/brainstorming design question than a specific question about a specific programming problem, and will probably end up closed as being "too broad".

Comment: I check the image and see that button that you want to click. I find that button is not a part of web page and it is displayed by the IE browser. So we cannot find it using VBA code. So there is no way available to click that save button using VBA code.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will explore trying to print it as PDF instead of saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the code of the website that loads the PDF, there is a big chance that the PDF URL may be somewhere in there, if it is, you can use VBA to get in that site and get the URL from the code, after getting the URL you could try to use the URLmon library which allows you to download files/websites based on a URL. Below is the code to download, you mentioned you are new to programming, you are going to have to look for the code to open the website, navigate to it and search for the URL in the html code. (Again, before you start building this code, first manually check the HTML to confirm that the pdf URL is somewhere in there).

```
Option Explicit 
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFileA Lib "urlmon" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _ 
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, _ 
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long 

Public Sub DownloadPDF()
    getFile "http://www.website.com/path/file.pdf", "C:\Downloads\filename.pfd"
    if getFile = True Then MsgBox "Download success"
End Sub

Function getFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean 
    Dim downloadCheck As Long
    'We need a long variable because the library returns a number if the file downloaded or if it failed.
    downloadCheck = URLDownloadToFileA(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    'Check if the number is 0, if so, the file downloaded fine.
    If downloadCheck = 0 Then getFile = True 
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo.